# bash alias for shell pipe throws errors

Tags: macos, bash, alias, piping

I adapted the following piping command from https://superuser.com/questions/401133/pipe-output-of-awk-to-kill-9 to quit *all* Microsoft goodies after reloading the Microsoft User Database

```
ps -Acx | grep Microsoft | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

This works as advertized, but when I use an alias

```
psm="ps -Acx | grep Microsoft | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill"
```

I get a lot of errors, e.g.

```
kill: illegal process id: ??<br>
kill: illegal process id: 0:05.40<br>
kill: illegal process id: Microsoft<br>
kill: illegal process id: Excel<br>
kill: illegal process id: ??<br>
kill: illegal process id: 0:00.04<br>
kill: illegal process id: Microsoft<br>
kill: illegal process id: AU<br>
kill: illegal process id: Daemon<br>
kill: illegal process id: ??<br>
kill: illegal process id: 0:17.95<br>
kill: illegal process id: Microsoft<br>
kill: illegal process id: PowerPoint<br>
```

Can somebody explain what is going wrong here?

Thx - Harald -

Comment: Do you have `pkill` available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should quote the $ in alias

```
psm="ps -Acx | grep Microsoft | awk '{print \$1}' | xargs kill"
```